# How can I obtain a HBITMAP or HICON from a Direct2D bitmap?

Tags: c++, direct2d

Is there any way to obtain a `HBITMAP` or `HICON` from a `ID2D1Bitmap *` using Direct2D? I am using [this function to load the bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756686%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The reason I ask is because I am creating my level editor tool and would like to draw a PNG image on a standard button control.

I know that you can do this using GDI+:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap;

Gdiplus::Bitmap b(L"a.png");
b.GetHBITMAP(NULL, &hBitmap);

SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_BUTTON1), BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);
```

Is there any equivalent, simple solution using Direct2D? If possible, I would like to render multiple PNG files (some with transparency) on a single button.

Answer (score 1):

Direct2D bitmaps are hardware device dependent resources and not generally easily accessible from the CPU side of the system. [They don't even have lock or map methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371109%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This makes it difficult to get at the pixels of a bitmap; it's not really designed to be used that way.

If you only have the D2D bitmap object available, you can render it to a [`HWND`-backed render target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371461%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and from there you can [get the `HWND`'s device context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and with that you can [create a compatible bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [blit from the render target DC to your new bitmap's DC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is obviously exceedingly clunky.

*However*, in [your link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756686%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you indicate that you are passing through the [WIC bitmap source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object to load your pixel data. If you cache that object for your level editor, you can more easily obtain the pixels, since `IWICBitmapSource` has [`CopyPixels` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can use to dump the bitmap data into a raw byte array (although the [`Lock` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be better if you want to avoid a lot of copies). From there you can create an `HBITMAP` or `HICON` from the raw bytes in the traditional fashion.

(If your bitmap ended up backed by a D3D texture or DXGI surface instead, you could also use the pixel access methods of those interfaces.)